# References about conic bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry

I'm interested in stable rationality of conic bundles by means of Brauer group/unramified cohomology non-triviality, and I was wondering if there are some references for the basic properties of conic bundles.

With basic I mean, other than some definitions and examples, some birational geometry, the results investigating unirationality, the associatiation with Brauer classes and so on. It seems to me that this material is mostly scattered around a lot of different papers, each one with a different formalism.